# Python3 vulnerabilities

Tags: apt, package-management, python, security, python3

Can anyone help me to understand difference between these two python outputs.

```
root@ip-192-168-20-21:~# apt install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


root@ip-192-168-20-21:~# apt install python3.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3.6 is already the newest version (3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

root@ip-192-168-20-21:~# python3 --version
Python 3.6.9

cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

My problem is Python 3.6.9 has lot of security vulnerabilities such as `CVE-2021-3177`. As per https://ubuntu.com/security/cve-2021-3177 this vulnerability has been fixed in `(3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4)` and released.

OS servers are up2date with the latest Ubuntu patches. However, My VA tool still reporting the same vulnerabilities are still exists in these systems. Does anyone know why this is happening and any idea to overcome this?

I hope this is happening my because my default python3 version still shows `Python 3.6.9` as in last command output. Can anyone advice on this?

Comment: I can imagine that the problem lies with the VA tool, which only checks the upstream version of Python, ignoring that the fix to this vulnerability has been backported, but I do not know that for sure.

Comment: Ask your VA tool provider why its misbehaving. There's nothing we or anybody from Ubuntu can do if it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Probably your VA tool does not check if the vulnerability actually exists, but only checks for reported software versions.

Comment: Yes. That's what my observations too. Thank you so much for you comments!

Answer (score 1):

The python3 command is linked to one of many installed python binaries.

You can see that there are others avaialble, for your specific example i imagine using `python3.6 --version` will produce output telling you it is `3.6.9-1~18.04ubuntu1.4` and simply running `python3.6` itself will start a python version 3.6 repl

To know which version variations of python3 binaries are installed and available try running `ls -la /usr/bin | grep python3` (drop the 3 to see any python 2 there also).

There can only by 1 python version linked to `python3` command, the output for the above command should give you something like `python3 -> python3.6`

You can verify which is current by doing `which python3` which shoudl be `/usr/bin/python3`.

It's not very good practice, but you can make your user session use a different version for the `python3` command via aliases: `alias python3='/usr/bin/python3.9'`. Best practice would be to `apt install python-venv` and then ina  project directory where a specific version is needed `/usr/bin/python3.9 -m venv .venv`